# Darboux's theorem when $f'(x) \neq 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

I recently came across Darboux's theorem and tried to prove from scratch (without using Darboux's theorem)that

if  $ f $ is differentiable for every $ x$ and $ f'(x) \neq 0 $ then $f'(x)$ is either always possitive or always negative.

This is my attempt:

Assume that there exist $a,b$ such that $f'(a)<0<f'(b)$
$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ so it has a max $M$ and a min $m$ in $[a,b]$ and so $M\geq f(x)\geq m , x\in[a,b]$ We know that the max, min cannot be in $(a,b)$ because $f'(x)\neq0$ so they must be either $a$ or $b$

This is how "far" i managed to do on my own , I am not sure if this is even the right way to approach this problem . Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean without using the mean value theorem?

Comment: We dont know if $f'$ is continuous so we cannot use the mean value theorem anyway

Comment: Derivability suffices, you do not need to assume that $f$ is $\mathcal C^1$ to apply mvt

Comment: What do you mean when you write that you intend to prove Darboux's theorem “without using Darboux's theorem”? How could it be otherwise?

Comment: It is not stated that $f'$ is differentiable we only know that the first derivative of $f$ exists and nothing about the second derivative .

Comment: Your proof attempt is in the right lines, but I'd add that to infer the max/min don't lie in $(a,b)$ you are invoking Rolle's theorem. I think this should be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Once again, there is no need to consider the second derivatives of $f$, just the existence of first derivatives with no further regularity assumptions suffice. Julio Puerta's proof uses the same arguments as for the standard proof of the MVT via Rolle's theorem which in turn is proved by a compacity argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume WLOG $f'(a)<0<f'(b)$ (otherwise consider $-f$ in the following reasoning).

As $f'(a)<0$ there exists some $\delta_1>0$ such that $$\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<0$$ for $x\in (a,a+\delta_1)$, so $$f(x)-f(a)<0$$ in that neighbourhood (as $x-a>0$) and the minimum of $f$ cannot be attained at $a$.

Similarly, as $f'(b)>0$ there exists some $\delta_2>0$ such that $$\dfrac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}>0$$ for $x\in (b-\delta_2,b)$, so $$f(x)-f(b)<0$$ in that neighbourhood (as $x-b<0$) and the minimum of $f$ isn't attained at $b$ either.

Therefore, the minimum is reached at some $c\in(a,b)$, and thus $f'(c)=0$.